# How to Transform Mesh Data From GLTF to OBJ Format

Tags: mesh, gltf, wavefront

I need to transform the vertex and index data of a mesh from a GLTF file into that of an OBJ file for the purposes of applying [V-HACD](https://github.com/kmammou/v-hacd).

I notice they aren't too dissimilar by comparing the mesh data of a cube in both formats:

| OBJ Verts | GLTF Verts | OBJ Index | GLTF Index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -100 | -1 | 1 | 3 |
| -100 | 0 | 2 | 6 |
| 100 | -0 | 0 | 0 |
| -100 | -100 | 3 | 10 |
| 100 | -100 | 6 | 19 |
| 100 | 100 | 2 | 8 |
| -100 | 0.375 | 7 | 23 |
| -100 | 1 | 4 | 14 |
| -100 | 0 | 6 | 20 |
| -100 | -1 | 5 | 15 |
| 100 | -0 | 0 | 2 |
| -100 | -100 | 4 | 13 |
| 100 | -100 | 6 | 18 |
| -100 | 100 | 0 | 1 |
| 100 | 0.125 | 2 | 7 |
| 100 | 0.25 | 3 | 11 |
| 100 | 0 | 5 | 16 |
| 100 | 0 | 7 | 22 |
| 100 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| -100 | -100 | 3 | 9 |
| -100 | -100 | 2 | 6 |
| 100 | 100 | 3 | 10 |
| 100 | 0.375 | 7 | 21 |
| -100 | 0 | 6 | 19 |
| _ | _ | 7 | 23 |
| _ | _ | 5 | 17 |
| _ | _ | 4 | 14 |
| _ | _ | 5 | 15 |
| _ | _ | 1 | 4 |
| _ | _ | 0 | 2 |
| _ | _ | 6 | 18 |
| _ | _ | 4 | 12 |
| _ | _ | 0 | 1 |
| _ | _ | 3 | 11 |
| _ | _ | 1 | 5 |
| _ | _ | 5 | 16 |

When attempting to use the GLTF data V-HACD throws an assertion error:

i < m_dim[0] && i >= 0 && j < m_dim[1] && j >= 0 && k < m_dim[2] && k >= 0

I'm guessing the vertex ordering is incompatible.

Comment: Vertex and index data is basically format-agnostic, it's how the graphics API represents a mesh. The same numbers can represent a cube in either format. I'm not sure where the specific numbers above come from... they are just cubes with different vertex coordinates and orders I think? But that difference is not inherent to a file format.

Comment: If you're creating glTF files I'd recommend sharing the code that generates them, and testing output against https://github.khronos.org/glTF-Validator/, perhaps to narrow down whether the glTF file you've created is valid or not.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy The code that produces the glTF file is the official plugin for blender from [KhronosGroup](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO). I validated the file with you link you provided.

Comment: You'll have to see my first comment, then. If you're looking for an explanation of the numbers in that table, it's just two different, mostly arbitrary, ways to make a cube. There's no 'official' glTF or OBJ version of a cube.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy Well that seems to narrow down the problem to V-HACD then. Thank you for the help!